# How do I open a given directory or folder in an existing Explorer window?

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd, explorer

I'm trying to create a shell command to open a given directory in the Explorer folder that the command is executed from.

I would add it as an entry to the right-click menu in regedit (`HKCR\Directory\background\shell`), but I can't figure out how to actually make the folder open in the current Explorer instance. (like the "open file location" option).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The open file location feature (COpenFileLocationMenu in shell32) is a shell extension, not a simple static command in the registry. COpenFileLocationMenu also implements `IObjectWithSite`.

When the [IContextMenu::InvokeCommand](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776096(v=vs.85).aspx) method in COpenFileLocationMenu is called, it calls `IUnknown_QueryService(..., SID_SInPlaceBrowser, IShellBrowser)` on its site so it can navigate the Explorer window with `IShellBrowser`.

Background menu items receive the folder location in `IShellExtInit::Initialize` and normal menu items can use `IShellBrowser::QueryActiveShellView` to get the view and then find the current location...

If you don't want to write a shell extension then you have to settle for the [scriptable](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130422-00/?p=4593) [ShellWindows object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773974%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) but you would have to do some guessing to find the correct window, perhaps by PInvoke'ing `GetForegroundWindow` from Powershell.